# Cannot create ThirdPartyResource

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a new ThirdPartyResource as per Kelsey Hightowers [kube-cert-manager guide](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kube-cert-manager/blob/master/docs/certificate-third-party-resource.md) but I'm getting this error:

```
Error from server: error when creating "certificate.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource
```

Something interesting from the verbose log:

```
POST https://104.155.48.255/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/thirdpartyresources 404 Not Found in 15 milliseconds
```

My cluster is created using GKE. Has just a single node running Kubernetes 1.3.2:

```
clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.244.0.0/14
createTime: '2016-08-01T09:35:39+00:00'
currentMasterVersion: 1.3.2
currentNodeCount: 1
currentNodeVersion: 1.3.2
endpoint: 104.155.48.255
initialClusterVersion: 1.3.2
instanceGroupUrls:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cs-cisco/zones/europe-west1-d/instanceGroupManagers/gke-minimesos-sonar-default-pool-3d02eeb3-grp
locations:
- europe-west1-d
loggingService: logging.googleapis.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThirdPartyResources were namespace-scoped alpha objects in 1.2, and they are now cluster-scoped in 1.3 (see the [1.3.0 Known Issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#thirdpartyresource)). Unfortunately, that means that a 1.2.x client will not know the right place to look for them (hence the 404 on the `/namespaces/default/thirdpartyresources` path).

You can either wait for kubectl 1.3.x to be rolled out with cloudsdk, or you can download the kubectl binaries directly from the [Kubernetes Releases](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases) page.

Comment: I downloaded the 1.3.2 binaries and confirmed that the client version was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot for the help!